# How to add styling to an option in ie 8 via JQuery

Tags: jquery, select, internet-explorer-8

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < paramLength; i++) {
    if (parameters[i].substr(0, 2) == '@_')//Required
    {
        $('#ddParam' + id).append($("<option style='font-style:italic'></option>").attr("value", parameters[i]).text(parameters[i] + ' (REQUIRED)'));
    }
    else
    {
        $('#ddParam' + id).append($("<option></option>").attr("value", parameters[i]).text(parameters[i]));
    }
}
```

NOTICE the STYLE tag in the OPTION -- this works fine for me in FF but (hang on to your hat) -- is not working in IE8 and that (unfortunately) is the browser that I am designing this app for....

Any suggestions and thanks!

Comment: Have you tried just adding it in with `.attr()` same as you are using for `value`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... I tried it ... ('.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", parameters[i]).attr("style", "font-size:30px")....)  ... .and it STILL WORKS in FF....but STILL DOESNT work in IE8.

Comment: Have you considered that styling capabilities of `<select>` elements is very browser specific.  IE may not support that.

Comment: Yes - I think this is the issue... if you will suggest this as the answer, I will mark it as such.  I just dont think I am able to style the <SELECT> elements in IE.

Comment: @toddy: As requested, an answer provided, with some further reading.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using classes - they are faster than adding single styles one by one. Use on jQuery object `addClass('classnameX')` or if you like styles: `css({'key1':'val1','key2':'val2'})`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered that styling capabilities of `<select>` elements is very browser specific.

IE did not support that prior to IE8, browsers vary in style on that element a good deal as they do with many form elements.

Further Questions:

- [Is it possible to style a select box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072239/is-it-possible-to-style-a-select-box)
- [Styling HTML SELECT in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646639/styling-html-select-in-internet-explorer)